# Jquery Calendar disable dates using beforeShow and beforeShowDay

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar

i have implemented code to disable dates using beforeShow and beforeShowDay callbacks

below code is for binding calendar to input

```
$("#start_on").datepicker({
            onSelect: function(date) {
                date_check(date);
            }, minDate: 0, dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
            beforeShow: get_booked,
            beforeShowDay: disable_if_not_available
        });
```

yes this is binding calendar to element

callback for `beforeShow`

```
function get_booked(inpput, inst) {
        var D = new Date();
        var month = (inst.selectedMonth == 0 ? D.getMonth() : inst.selectedMonth) + 1;
        var year = (inst.selectedYear == 0 ? D.getYear() : inst.selectedYear);
        dis_date = new Array();
        $.ajax({
            url: BASE_URL + "contest/get_booked",
            data: {year: year, month: month, id:<?php echo (isset($contest_data->id)) ? $contest_data->id : 0; ?>},
            dataType: "json", type: "POST",
            success: function(data) {
                for (var d in data) {
                    var D = data[d];
                    var start = D.start_on;
                    var d = start.split("-");
                    var sD = new Date(d[0], d[1] - 1, d[2]);
                    var end = D.end_on;
                    var d = end.split("-");
                    var eD = new Date(d[0], d[1] - 1, d[2]);
                    while (sD <= eD) {
                        dis_date.push(sD.getFullYear() + "-" + (sD.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + sD.getDate());
                        sD.setDate(sD.getDate() + 1);
                    }
                }
            }
        });

    }
```

callback for `beforeShowDay`

```
function disable_if_not_available(date) {
        var y = date.getFullYear(), m = date.getMonth() + 1, d = date.getDate();
        return [dis_date.indexOf(y + "-" + m + "-" + d) == -1];
    }
```

problem with this is that `disable_if_not_available` is getting called before `dis_date` get filled from `get_booked`. currently `disable_if_not_available` return always true because `dis_date` is empty so what i want to do is to call/return  `disable_if_not_available` only after i get response from `get_booked`

please ask if any doubt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because the entire initialization of the datepicker ends before the ajax call returns any value.

what you could do is start the ajax call and when the call ends, call the initialization of the datepicker.

example:

```
...
...
$.ajax({
    url: BASE_URL + "contest/get_booked",
    data: {year: year, month: month, id:<?php echo (isset($contest_data->id)) ? $contest_data->id : 0; ?>},
    dataType: "json",        
    type: "POST",        
    success: function(data) {        
        for (var d in data) {        
            var D = data[d];        
            var start = D.start_on;        
            var d = start.split("-");        
            var sD = new Date(d[0], d[1] - 1, d[2]);        
            var end = D.end_on;        
            var d = end.split("-");        
            var eD = new Date(d[0], d[1] - 1, d[2]);        
            while (sD <= eD) {        
                dis_date.push(sD.getFullYear() + "-" + (sD.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + sD.getDate());        
                sD.setDate(sD.getDate() + 1);        
            }        
        }        
        //CALL YOUR DatePicker Initialization
        initDatePicker();
    }

});
...
...




function initDatePicker(){
    $("#start_on").datepicker({/*Initialization values*/});
}
```

Comment: what you could do is when you click in the input field, instead of showing the calendar you could make the ajax call and fill your global variables. After it's done, you can call the Datepicker to open using 
    $("#start_on").datepicker("show");

Answer (score 0):

Simple Solution for this.just use 'async:false' in your ajax call.

Example:

...
...
$.ajax({
    url: BASE_URL + "contest/get_booked",
    data: {year: year, month: month, id:id)) ? $contest_data->id : 0; ?>},
    dataType: "json",
    type: "POST",
    async:false,
    success: function(data) {
...
...